# videos uploaded to firebase are 0 seconds long?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I have an app where you can upload videos to firebase. The problem I have recently encountered is that all videos uploaded to firebase are 0 sec long (This is when in the DB, before, as in in the app, they are of correct length), which is of course wrong.

Some things I've tried:

- I check how I upload which i also included bellow and it seems correct.
- thumbnail is of type UIImage
- The video right before I send it (in the preview I have in-app) the video looks perfect.

Another thing I noticed is that a thumbnail I upload with the video which is an image is being uploaded as a video.

```
        } else if let vidData = media.videoURL {
        print("VIDEO")
        let autoIDSto = "media\(media.numMedia).mov"
        print(autoIDSto)
        let autoID = "media\(media.numMedia)"

        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).child("post:\(postID)").child(autoIDSto)
        let postRef = childRef.child("Media")
        let uploadData = media.videoURL

        let uploadTask = storageRef.putFile(from: vidData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
            print("\(vidData) : Video data")
            guard let metadata = metadata else { return }

            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }

            storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
            //a bunch of code to add to DB
                        if let thumbnailImageData = media.thumbnailImage!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0) {
                            storageRef.putData(thumbnailImageData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
                                storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                                    if let thumbnail = url {
                                        mediaRef.updateChildValues(["thumbnail" : "\(thumbnail)"])
```

**Whats wrong and how can I fix it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the same path ( 1 with **mov** extension )

```
let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).child("post:\(postID)").child(autoIDSto)
```

to store the video/image thumbnail here

```
let uploadTask = storageRef.putFile(from: vidData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
```

and

```
storageRef.putData(thumbnailImageData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
```

There should be 2 different paths 1 with **mov** extension and another with **jpg** extension that you finally store the reference of both in 1 record in your database table